# Gatsby: Render new children without re-render another element in Layout

Tags: reactjs, layout, static, gatsby, rerender

I'm using Gatsby with `gatsby-plugin-layout` for my building website. I create my default layout at `src/layouts/index.js`, like this:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

    return (
        <ContextProviderComponent>
            <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
            <div
                style={{
                    margin: `0 auto`,
                    maxWidth: 960,
                    padding: `0px 1.0875rem 1.45rem`,
                    paddingTop: 0,
                }}
            >
                <main>{children}</main>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </ContextProviderComponent>
    )
}

Layout.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

And in my child page, I **DO NOT** wrape my page by `Layout` component, like this:

```
const SecondPage = () => (
  <>
    <SEO title="Page two" />
    <h1>Hi from the second page</h1>
    <p>Welcome to page 2</p>
    <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
  </>
)

export default SecondPage
```

So when I change the `children` (eg: click to Link to switch to another route), I do not wanna re-render another component in Layout (eg: Header, Footer ...).
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: put Header and footer in index component

Comment: From what I see you are already doing it. So, what is not working? Errors?

Comment: @Z.Zlatev: No error. I just wanna `Header` and `Footer` does not re-render when `{children}` change on route change.